# Epsilon and Delta proof of $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{ x}$

Tags: epsilon-delta

I need to prove $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{ x}$
I first found the limit to be $\frac{1}{4}$ by using l'hopital's rule.
By definition i need to find a $\delta > 0$ for every $\epsilon >0$ 
Then i will have $|x-0|<\delta$ and 
$$|\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{ x}-\frac{1}{4}|<\epsilon$$

I have tried multiple ways to simplify, but I can't seem to get it in the form of just $x$. And I am a bit confused on how to pick my delta in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets much simple when you write
$$
\frac{2−\sqrt{4−x}}x = \frac{(2-\sqrt{4−x})(2+\sqrt{4−x})}{x(2+\sqrt{4−x})}
=\frac1{2+\sqrt{4−x}}
$$
then:

\begin{align}
\left|
        \frac1{2+\sqrt{4−x}} - \frac 14
\right|
&=   \frac{|2 - \sqrt{4-x}|}{4(2+\sqrt{4−x})} 
\le \frac{|2 - \sqrt{4-x}|}8 
\\ &=  
\frac{|2 - \sqrt{4-x}|(2 + \sqrt{4-x})}{8(2 + \sqrt{4-x})} 
\\ &= \frac{|x|}{8(2 + \sqrt{4-x})} 
\le \frac{|x|}{16}
\end{align}
so just take $\delta = 16\epsilon$.

Comment: Forgot to factor out the $x$ at the end. Im still new to this style of proof. So  I want my $|x|<\delta$ to get into the form of  $|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}-\frac{1}{4}|$? So I got tried found a common denominator and got $\frac{1-\sqrt{4-x}}{4+2\sqrt{4-x}}$ but I dont see how i can get $\delta$ into this form. Unless I am thinking of this wrong.

Comment: Did not see you added more to it. Thank you.

Comment: To keep things simple, try to keep the variable in one place in the expressoin (when possible).

Comment: Last question. Looking at your work I see that you are finding a large enough $\epsilon$ so that the problem becomes easier to solve for $x$. Is that what you were doing there? More specifically is that a recommended thought process when solving these types of proofs.

Comment: no. Fix $\epsilon$ without constrains, and then look for a convenient $\delta$